# Google Sheet sends email from list when cell condition met

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm still very new to scripting and can't work out why the below script doesn't work

```
function sendReturnEmail(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  if(event.range.getA1Notation().indexOf("K") && sheet.getRange("K" + row).getDisplayValue() == "Approved")
  {
  var rowVals = getActiveRowValues(sheet);
  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
  var to = rowVals.user;
  var subject = "Allocation request approved";
  var body = "Your allocation request of " +rowVals.quantity + " cases on " + rowVals.date + " from " + rowVals.depot + " has been approved. <br \> <br \>"
    + "Regards, <br \> <br \>" +rowVals.analyst + "<br \> CPF Team";  
Logger.log(aliases);
  GmailApp.sendEmail(to,subject,body,    
                     {from: aliases[0]})
    ;
  }}

  function getActiveRowValues(sheet){
  var cellRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  // get depot value
  var depotCell = sheet.getRange("E" + cellRow);
  var depot = depotCell.getDisplayValue();
  // get date value
  var dateCell = sheet.getRange("F" + cellRow);
  var date = dateCell.getDisplayValue();
  // get quantity value
  var quantCell = sheet.getRange("G" + cellRow);
  var quant = quantCell.getDisplayValue();
  // return an object with your values
  var analystCell = sheet.getRange("J" + cellRow);
  var analyst = analystCell.getDisplayValue();
  var userCell = sheet.getRange("O" + cellRow);
  var user = userCell.getDisplayValue();
  return {
    depot: depot,
    date: date,
    quantity: quant,
    analyst: analyst,
    user: user
  } }
}
```

The sheet is question has several scripts running in it, one of them being this:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Allocation Requests" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 2) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 13);
          nextCell.setValue(Session.getEffectiveUser());
      }
  }
```

I now want the sheet to send an email to the email address captured using the above script (which works fine) when the corresponding cell in column K is manually changed to "Approved."

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong. I get no errors when it runs, but I'm not getting an email. I've searched other questions but none have helped. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onedit why cannot send email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014515/onedit-why-cannot-send-email)

Comment: I've tried disabling some of the other scripts but it didn't make a difference. All the other scripts run fine.

Comment: How is the function sendReturnEmail(event) being called?? if you run it manually in the editor does it send an email?