# onEdit Email Notification in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a way to trigger an automatic email notification to myself when any value within a column of data ("Column H") drops below a certain threshold. Ideally, the notification would include the name associated with the value, which is stored in a separate column of the spreadsheet ("Column A").

My best guess so far is that I need to use an onEdit function, which has a condition that checks the values within the specific column and then sends a email when a value meets that condition.

Here's what I have so far, but I'm having issues with completing this.

```
function onEdit(e){
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var data = sheet.getDataRange("H1:H200").getValues();
   var newValue = e.value;
}
if (newValue < "10"){
   MailApp.sendEmail("test@test.com","TEST", "TEST");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Update: Here's what I currently have, following the creation of an installable trigger. I'm getting a 'value' undefined error at the moment and think that possibly syntax/formatting are to blame.

```
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(StationeryEdited)
        .forSpreadsheet(ss)
        .onEdit()
        .create();
    }

function StationeryEdited(e){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var data = sheet.getRange(2, 8, 200, 1).getValues();
    var newValue = e.value;
    if (newValue < "10"){
        MailApp.sendEmail("justin@bond.co", "TEST", "TEST");
    }
}
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Mind you that you  need to use an installable onedit trigger [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014515/onedit-why-cannot-send-email)

Comment: Hi Robin, Thanks for the heads up about the installable trigger. I've added to my code in order to account for that. At the moment, I'm getting a new error: "Cannot read property "value" from undefined. (line 4, file "Code")."

Comment: Are you trying to run the onEdit in the script editor? That won't work as it runs without any parameters passed to it

Comment: Thanks, Robin. That's really helpful! I've got the script running, but I'm still having authorization issues, despite switching to an installable onedit trigger. When I look at the execution log, everything seems to execute, but I receive an error saying that I'm not authorized to send the email.

Comment: Did you rename your function when adding the installable trigger ?

Comment: Did it not ask you to allow access to gmail when you tried to run it in the script editor?

Comment: @Sergeinsas: I didn't rename my function when adding the installable trigger. Is that something I should do?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach: Gmail did ask for access the first time I ran it in the script editor, but it hasn't done so since then.

Comment: @jbarry1 yes, otherwise both triggers could try to run, that's maybe why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Does this feature doesnt help you?

`Tools >> Notification Rules`

Comment: Thanks. This feature won't really help because I'm only looking to receive an email notification when a value in Column H drops below a certain threshold. Using those notification rules would mean that I'll receive an email whenever any edits are made.

Comment: well if thats ur concern, much better to create a custom code which is the google script. add some condition also. i think your code posted is quite enough based on what you need.